# Interior walls question

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv

I am quite new to Blender. I am currently creating a replica of a building to be used in a VR simulation at some point (I have a few years to learn how to achieve this).

I have been reading about breaking up a building into parts to make it easier to work with as I plan to move the model to Unreal Engine once I have learned how to use that. That is fine, I get why that would be a useful thing to do.

Currently, I am about to learn all about UV unwrapping and baking. Whilst modeling the interior walls, would it be better to include objects on the walls such as switches, notice boards, pictures, cupboards, etc, or make those as separate objects and add them later?

I currently haven't included them but I am still at a stage where I could add them. I know I am in the early stages of learning but I could do with knowing what I will be unwrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ability to move the objects around the wall and maybe even use it in different walls, I would recommend keeping it as separate objects.
If its a one-off building with no reusable assets, than you can make it as one object.
I prefer the first way as it will give you a bunch of reusable assets.

Answer (score 0):

You could model the wall decorations as separate objects, and then just parent them to the wall.

As Daklinus said already, best practice would be to model them all as individual objects.